# css letter space issue

Tags: css, letter-spacing

i need to set letter space to a negative value. but i found a problem.

when set letter space css attribute to a negative value on p tag. p tag bounding box doen't contain text as below

[image]

here is code

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: -0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Hello, I am Justin
  </p>
</div>
```

is there any way p tag bounding box can contain text?  or impossible?
please give me any idea

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`letter-spacing` also applies to the last character, unfortunately. Even though it should be only affecting spacings between letters. This is [a known bug that has been discussed for a long time](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1518).

Currently, to get rid of the negative `letter-spacing` after the last character, there are several work-arounds. One of them is to add a padding on the right to counter it:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: -0.3em;
  padding-inline-end: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Hello, I am Justin
  </p>
</div>
```

Or utilizing a pseudo element and giving it a `letter-spacing: initial`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: -0.3em;
}

p::after {
  content: '\2002'; /* &ensp; */
  letter-spacing: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Hello, I am Justin
  </p>
</div>
```